# Mouse Cursor Disappear While RDP

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

In our environment, users RDP to their company desktop through a remote desktop gateway. Occasionally, we heard users report to us that the mouse cursor disappeared while they were RDPing to the company desktop.

This problem has been bothering us for a very long time. One workaround we found was changing the mouse cursor to "large" instead of the system default.  But this is not a 100% fix. From time to time, we can still see the mouse cursor disappearing even with the cursor size changed.

Unfortunately, even with lots of testing of different scenarios, it seems we just can't draw a conclusion exactly what's causing the problem.

I'm wondering if anyone here had seen this issue before?

Thanks,
SC

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but because I had the same problem and I couldn't find any solution to fix it and I found the fix by hopelessly changing every settings for RDP I will answer it.

In RDP settings, the Display Bit-depth should be 24 bit.

[image: RDP Dsiplay Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions, but they did not work.  What ended up working for me, does not make sense, but thought I would post in case it helps someone else.

In the section, [Solution 2. Change mouse settings](https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/how-to-fix-mouse-cursor-disappearing-on-remote-desktop-0427.html).  By turning on Mouse Keys, my cursor immediately appeared.  Now it works each time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one way to reliably reproduce this problem: When making a RDP connection from my Windows 10 laptop to Windows Server 2016, using the laptop's touch screen causes the standard cursor to permanently disappear or change. The state persists even after closing and reconnecting the RDP session.

Workaround: By opening the mouse cursor customization dialog (Control Panel -> Mouse -> Pointers tab, or search "Mouse cursor" in the start menu) and pressing OK/Enter (without changing anything) the current mouse theme will be re-applied and the cursor returns to normal until the next time I accidentally bump the touch screen.